# How to find repetitive patterns in a string with regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

For example, given such a string:
`I like bla blab blah chocolate I like bla blob bla cheese`
I'd like to find all the strings that starts with "I like" then followed by some text and the value.

My problem is that it detects it but `.*` takes everything until the end returning then one match instead of two.

```
In [37]: s = 'I like bla blab blah chocolate I like bla blob bla cheese'

In [38]: p = re.compile(r'(I like) .* (\w+)', re.IGNORECASE)

In [39]: p.findall(s)
Out[39]: [('I like', 'cheese')]
```

I am expecting:
`[('I like', 'chocolate'), ('I like', 'cheese')]`

Comment: What is your expected output? `list(filter(None, f' {s} '.split(' I like ')))`?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\b(I like \S.*?)\s*(?=\bI like |$)` https://regex101.com/r/60ikyc/1

Comment: I am expecting: `[('I like', 'chocolate'), ('I like', 'cheese')]`

Comment: How is it supposed to know to ignore "blah"? What's special about it?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes like this, but is it still possible to capture the subsets in each group rather than each chunk?

Comment: You you can use `\b(I like ).*?(\w+)\s*(?=\bI like |$)`  https://regex101.com/r/mosR7P/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Also, the example contained 2 patterns but it's unknown how many patterns there will be. I saw you added it twice to match the example.

Comment: @Mike I would not match `chocolate vanilla pudding` in  `I like bla blab blah chocolate vanilla pudding`, just a single word before `I like`

Comment: @Thefourthbird actually nevermind my last question, I saw that it captures more than two.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Can you please explain how this works? I am going to try to use it on my real use case that is a bit more complicated than these examples.

Comment: @Mike No, there are not 2 parts with `I like` to match. You should read Wiktor's answer. There is a lookahead asserting `I like` or the end of the string after the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\b(I like)\b.*?(\w+)(?=\s*(?:\bI like\b|$))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7M94sR/2/). *Details*:

- `\b(I like)\b` - Group 1, `I like` matched as whole words
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more letters/digits/`_` (and some more connector punctuation)
- `(?=\s*(?:\bI like\b|$))` - a positive lookahead that matches a location in string that is immediately followed with

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?:\bI like\b|$)` - either `I like` as whole words or end of string.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9HJa4L):

```py
import re
s = 'I like bla blab blah chocolate I like bla blob bla cheese'
print( re.findall(r'\b(I like)\b.*?(\w+)(?=\s*(?:\bI like\b|$))', s) )
# => [('I like', 'chocolate'), ('I like', 'cheese')]
```